# Is there a way to make a powershell script from this cmd example?

Tags: powershell

I am currently using the below as part of a batch script to backup files over FTP. I am working on making a powershell version of this and am having trouble finding the right commands to take the place of this section. Does anyone have any suggestions? Ive been working on this for a while now with no luck.

```
ping %IP%

echo open %IP%>> temp.txt
echo >> temp.text
echo >> temp.text
echo bin>> temp.txt
echo prompt>> temp.txt
echo mget *.*>> temp.txt
echo bye>> temp.txt

ftp -n -s:temp.txt
:del temp.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

What is this actually supposed to do ? Just test if PC is up, then transfer a file via FTP ?

Comment: Yes. It tests the connection and transfers multiple files via FTP. Specifically its for making backups of robot controllers. I am having limited success with finding info for FTP using powershell.